# min-width media query not working on ipad?

Tags: ipad, media-queries

Why isnt the following media query being picked up on iPads in landscape mode?

```
@media all and (min-device-width: 1000px) {
    css here
}
```

Or

```
@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
    css here
}
```

I want this css to target any browser which is 1000px wide or over, not just ipads. For this reason id rather work with the 2nd option of min-width not min-device-width if possible. Both versions work fine with firefox on my PC. 
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The iPad is always reporting its width as 768px and its height as 1024px, so you have to find out how it is rotated with `orientation` and use `min-device-height:1000px` like so:

```css
     /* This will apply to all screens with a width 999px and smaller */
* {
     color:green;
     background-color:black;
}

     /*
       This will apply to all screens larger then 1000px wide 
       including landscape ipad but not portrait ipad. 
      */
@media (orientation:landscape) and (min-device-height:1000px),
       all and (min-width:1000px) {
    * {
        color:white;
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

Results:

- iPad

  - Portrait       - **green** text - **black** background
  - Landscape - **white** text  - **red** background
- iPhone

  - Portrait       - **green** text - **black** background
  - Landscape - **green** text - **black** background
- Computer (resolution)

  - 1680x1050 - **white** text  - **red** background
  - 800x600     - **green** text - **black** background

Using chrome & firefox (does anyone even use IE anymore?)

References:
[w3 media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation)
[Safari CSS Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002050)
[Optimizing Web Content](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517-SW2)

Comment: A bit annoying the iPad works in this way but thanks for your answer.

Comment: @jdln Np. I agree that there should really be a better way of accomplishing this. Hopefully there will be some better CSS standards for mobile devices and tablets in the future.

Answer (score 1):

From http://perishablepress.com/press/2010/10/20/target-iphone-and-ipad-with-css3-media-queries/

```
/* iPad [portrait + landscape] */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    .selector-01 { margin: 10px; }
    .selector-02 { margin: 10px; }
    .selector-03 { margin: 10px; }
}
```

It looks like the `screen` attribute may be required.

Comment: Your code does work on ipads but I want to target other tablets and also desktop browsers over 100px wide.

Comment: It sounds like adding some javascript device detection might be a more robust solution for you.  I like modernizr with a combination of custom code I wrote to append the browser and version as html classes so I know exactly what I'm working with.  I just don't trust the browsers enough to do what they're supposed to so I like to find browser specific issues and attack them directly in a few minutes instead of trying to find a perfect solution that takes hours or days.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I thought with javascript you could append the browser width and height as custom <html> classes that you could add something like .min1000Width. Then you get to have vanilla CSS without media queries that even the least capable browser would understand.

Answer (score 0):

If found this works great for the new iPad

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) and (min-device-height:1000px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
    * {
        color:white;
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I'm not sure why

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {

 /* css here */

}
```

didn't work for you. Possibly something changed with the iPad since this question was first posted?

Here's a working example:
live view: http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/Bn4ah/show/
edit view: http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/Bn4ah/

Also be sure to include

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in the head of your page.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use a simple media query like this: 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px)
    {css here}
but I wouldn't trigger on an iPad pro 10.5' I was testing on, I increase it to 900px (for portrait) and it worked just fine, I think because of the retina display you need to compensate, it may work fine on old iPads non-retina.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to write a media query for tablet, I actually encountered the problem of the iPad underreporting its dimensions. When I tried to use `@media screen and ( min-width: 768px )`, my styles were being applied to other tablet devices, but ignored by the iPad. I started playing around with the Responsive device model in developer tools, and I stumbled onto the solution. For some reason, my styles would apply when I sized the screen down to `760px`. So, I edited the media query to read **`@media screen and ( min-width: 760px )`** and everything started working as expected.