# Media query min-width:1000px including iPad landscape

Tags: css, ipad, responsive-design, media-queries, desktop

How can I target devices which are wider than 1000 pixels? That is, including iPad in landscape mode and most desktops but excluding iPad in portrait mode.

I have found [how to target iPad specifically](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/):

```
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
```

However, I would prefer if my media queries could be shaped by at what widths the content prompted layout changes rather than by specific devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't need to try and target specific devices at all.

In your main CSS just include:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {

/* CSS styles for viewports 1000px and up */  

}
```

and in the head of your page include

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

EDIT
Here is a working example which you can check in an iPad:
Live:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/Bn4ah/show/
Code view: http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/Bn4ah

Good luck!

Comment: Does `width=device-width` stop the iPad from reporting width=768px and height=1024px in landscape mode?

Comment: @FredrikP , please see my edit. With CSS media queries, I find you are rewarded if you keep it simple and don't over think it. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I managed to get hold of an iPad and checked it. (I really should buy one.) It worked just as you said.

Comment: Seems like JSFiddle hack to add viewport meta isn't working anymore

Comment: The jsFiddle looks OK to me @ArtemShafranov, please check again. If the width of the preview frame is > 1000px you should see the body background change from white to grey.

Answer (score 1):

While that article you referenced from CSS-Tricks is a very handy reference (and Chris Coyier is my nerd-idol) it may be a bit misleading.  Media queries at their core are just fancy `if` statements, and if the entire statement evaluates as `true`, then the corresponding style sheet or style rules are applied, following the normal cascading rules.

Let's look at a common media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) { ... }
```

Notice the `screen` parameter.  It says nothing about the device width nor browser chrome.  Read in plain English, it says "if the media we're working on is the *screen*, and if that screen is a minimum of 768px or bigger, use *these styles*.

So, **to answer your question:** to target *screens* that are larger than 1000px wide, try this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) { ... }
```

Just remember that you're targeting *all screens* at least 1000 pixels wide.  If you need to target specific devices, I recommend using JavaScript to handle specific UserAgent targeting.

Comment: From what I have heard it seems that the iPad always reports its width as 768px and height as 1024px, regardless of whether it is in landscape or portrait mode. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726411/min-width-media-query-not-working-on-ipad#answer-7758356. This was the reason why I posted my question in the first place (and probably should have been included in the original question).

Comment: +1 for answering the question. David got the answer for addressing my further questions.